# Deleting many events from a calendar within date range and a certain extended property value using Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I know how to display all of the events within a certain calendar using **Microsoft Graph**:

```
var oEvents = await _graphClient
                    .Me
                    .Calendars[oCalendar.Id]
                    .Events
                    .Request()
                    .GetAsync();
if(oEvents?.Count > 0)
{
    foreach(Event oEvent in oEvents)
    {
        string strEventInfo = $"Subject: {oEvent.Subject}" + Environment.NewLine;
        //strEventInfo += $"Body: {oEvent.BodyPreview}" + Environment.NewLine;
        strEventInfo += $"Times: Start - {oEvent.Start.DateTime} End - {oEvent.End.DateTime}" + Environment.NewLine;
        //strEventInfo += $"Location: {oEvent.Location.DisplayName}" + Environment.NewLine;
        strEventInfo += $"All Day: {oEvent.IsAllDay}" + Environment.NewLine;
        Console.WriteLine(strEventInfo);
    }
}
```

What I am now trying to find out is how to **delete** all events within a certain **date range** that have an extended property of **TruckleSoft1** with a value of **CLM_MidweekMeeting**.

I get confused with most of the online documentation because it is presented in a format that I don't use in my coding and I can't quite workout yet how to translate that into my requirements.

In the **ASPNET Snippets** it provides an example of deleting a **specific** event:

```
public async Task<List<ResultsItem>> DeleteEvent(GraphServiceClient graphClient, string id)
{
    List<ResultsItem> items = new List<ResultsItem>();

    // Delete the event.
    await graphClient.Me.Events[id].Request().DeleteAsync();

    items.Add(new ResultsItem
    {

        // This operation doesn't return anything.
        Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { Resource.No_Return_Data, "" }
        }
    });
    return items;
}
```

I see the important line:

```
await graphClient.Me.Events[id].Request().DeleteAsync();
```

But I understand there is a way to do what I need much more simply. I have the two dates (start / end) in `DateTime` objects (date only).

What is the right way to do what I want?

Thank you.

## Update

I think I am supposed to use the following to delete the required events:

```
var oEvents = await _graphClient
                    .Me
                    .Calendars[oCalendar.Id]
                    .Events
                    .Filter(" ?????? ")
                    .Expand(" ????? ")
                    .Request()
                    .GetAsync();
```

I understand that **Filter** would specify the date range but can work out what goes in there. And I understand that we use **Expand** with respects to extended properties. **Am I on the right track?**

**Assuming I am, does this mean we will have to iterate any returns list and delete each event one by one?** Sounds idea for batch, but that is another question as I am also struggled to get worked example for batching.

## Update 2

OK, I looked at the resource provided in the answer and this [additional resource](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty_get) so I ended up with this code:

```
// The first thing we need to do is delete the existing events
if(oData.Settings.CalendarEntryType == "CLM_MidweekMeeting")
{
    // We only want events within the desired date range
    string strFilter = String.Format(
        "start/dateTime ge '{0}T00:00' and end/dateTime le '{1}T23:59'",
        oData.Settings.StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
        oData.Settings.EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

    // We only want events of the right type
    string strExpand = "singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq '{TruckleSoft1}' and value eq '{CLM_MidweekMeeting}')";


    // Select the events (if any) and delete them
    var oEvents = await _graphClient
                         .Me
                         .Calendars[oData.Settings.CalendarID]
                         .Events
                         .Request()
                         .Filter(strFilter)
                         .Expand(strExpand)
                         .GetAsync();
    if (oEvents?.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Event oEvent in oEvents)
        {
            // Delete the event (Do I need to use the specific calendar events list?)
            await _graphClient.Me.Events[oEvent.Id].Request().DeleteAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an exception:

> Code: ErrorInvalidProperty Message: PropertyId values may only be in one of the following formats: 'MapiPropertyType
>   namespaceGuid Name propertyName', 'MapiPropertyType namespaceGuid Id
>   propertyId' or 'MapiPropertyType propertyTag'.

This implies to me that when I followed the sample code and did:

```
// Extended Properties
var extendedProperties = new EventSingleValueExtendedPropertiesCollectionPage();
extendedProperties.Add(new SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty
{
    Id = String.Format("String {{{0}}} Name {1}", Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "TruckleSoft1"),
    Value = oData.Settings.CalendarEntryType
});
```

It is not a good idea to use `Guid.NewGuid()` like that as it will always change. It seems to me I must manually create the Guid using the generator and build a static string. Then I use this same string when deleting an event and creating an event. Correct?

## Update 3

I changed my code:

```
private static readonly string _PropertyCLM_MidweekMeeting = "String {~~~~} Name TruckleSoft1";
```

Then, I adjusted the query code:

```
// We only want events within the desired date range
string strFilter = String.Format(
    "start/dateTime ge '{0}T00:00' and end/dateTime le '{1}T23:59'",
    oData.Settings.StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
    oData.Settings.EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

// We only want events of the right type
string strExpand = $"singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq '{_PropertyCLM_MidweekMeeting}' and value eq 'CLM_MidweekMeeting')";



// Select the events (if any) and delete them
var oEvents = await _graphClient
                     .Me
                     .Calendars[oData.Settings.CalendarID]
                     .Events
                     .Request()
                     .Filter(strFilter)
                     .Expand(strExpand)
                     .GetAsync();
if (oEvents?.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (Event oEvent in oEvents)
    {
        // Delete the event (Do I need to use the specific calendar events list?)
        await _graphClient.Me.Events[oEvent.Id].Request().DeleteAsync();
    }
}
```

But I get an exception:

> Code: ErrorInvalidUrlQueryFilter
>   Message: The query filter contains one or more invalid nodes.

So `strExpand` is:

```
singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {~~~~} Name TruckleSoft1' and value eq 'CLM_MidweekMeeting')
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete only works against an individual `event`, you cannot execute a delete against a collection.

Using [batching](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching) might be a viable solution but keep in mind that this is still in preview and [not supported by the .NET SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/136) yet. In order to use it, you'll need to construct and submit your HTTP request (and handle the response) yourself.

## Update by Original Poster

This additional resource was useful: [Get singleValueLegacyExtendedProperty](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty_get)

If you are interested in just the **id** then you use **Expand**. But if you are interested in *both* the **id** *and* **value** then you actually use **Filter**!

> ```
> GET /me/events?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/id eq '{id_value}' and ep/value eq '{property_value}')
> ```

The **Guid** must also be static in the application (as noted in the updated question):

```
private static readonly string _PropertyCLM_MidweekMeeting = "String {~~~~} Name TruckleSoft1";
```

Thus, to filter on both a date range and a extended property id and value the code is:

```
// The first thing we need to do is delete the existing events
if(oData.Settings.CalendarEntryType == "CLM_MidweekMeeting")
{
    // We only want events within the desired date range
    string strFilterDateRange = String.Format(
        "start/dateTime ge '{0}T00:00' and end/dateTime le '{1}T23:59'",
        oData.Settings.StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
        oData.Settings.EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

    // We only want events of the right type
    string strFilterProperty = $"singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/id eq '{_PropertyCLM_MidweekMeeting}' and ep/value eq 'CLM_MidweekMeeting')";

    string strFilter = strFilterDateRange + " and " + strFilterProperty;

    // Select the events (if any) and delete them
    var oEvents = await _graphClient
                         .Me
                         .Calendars[oData.Settings.CalendarID]
                         .Events
                         .Request()
                         .Filter(strFilter)
                         .GetAsync();
    if (oEvents?.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Event oEvent in oEvents)
        {
            // Delete the event (Do I need to use the specific calendar events list?)
            await _graphClient.Me.Events[oEvent.Id].Request().DeleteAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. What about the filter / expand syntax to limit results returned to date range and extended property value?

Comment: These are string values. You can read about how they are constructed at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters

Comment: I am encountering problems. Please see my updated question.

Comment: I have updated your answer with my results that seem to work for me and flesh out the answer to my overall question. If I am wrong with anything please adjust. :)